# Creating new string somehow changing value of old string? | C

Tags: c, nand2tetris

I'm doing project 6 in nand2tetris - where you have to make a HACK assembler.

Right now, all I want to go is create a big string that stores the data in the assembly file, without the Windows 0x0d and duplicate new lines (so no 0x0a followed by a 0x0a).

Here's my header file - assembler.h

```
typedef struct string
{
    int length;
    char *the_string;   
} string;
```

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "assembler.h"

string *put_the_entire_file_into_one_big_string(FILE *the_entire_file);
string *take_out_the_double_lines(string *the_string);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check the number of arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Provide only one argument: the name of the assembly file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Check if the argument is an .asm file
    int a = sizeof(argv[1]);
    if (!((argv[1][a - 5] == '.') and (argv[1][a - 4] == 'a') and (argv[1][a - 3] == 's') and (argv[1][a - 2] == 'm')))
    {
        printf("not an .asm file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Check if the file exists
    FILE *the_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (the_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("File doesn't exist. Maybe you mistyped it?");
        return -1;
    }
    string *the_big_string_thats_the_entire_file = put_the_entire_file_into_one_big_string(the_file);

    string *the_big_string_but_without_mulitple_line_breaks_in_a_row = take_out_the_double_lines(the_big_string_thats_the_entire_file);

    free(the_big_string_thats_the_entire_file->the_string);

    printf("%s", the_big_string_but_without_mulitple_line_breaks_in_a_row->the_string);

    free(the_big_string_but_without_mulitple_line_breaks_in_a_row->the_string);
    
    fclose(the_file);
}

string *put_the_entire_file_into_one_big_string(FILE *the_entire_file)
{
    string *one_big_string;
    one_big_string->the_string = malloc(sizeof(char));
    one_big_string->length = 0;
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        c = fgetc(the_entire_file);
        if (c == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (c == 0x0d)
        {
            continue;
        }
        one_big_string->the_string[one_big_string->length] = c;
        one_big_string->length++;
        one_big_string->the_string = realloc(one_big_string->the_string, sizeof(char) * (one_big_string->length + 1));
    }
    return one_big_string;
}

string *take_out_the_double_lines(string *the_old_string)
{
    string *new_string;
    new_string->the_string = malloc(sizeof(char));
    new_string->length = 1;
    new_string->the_string[0] = the_old_string->the_string[0];
    new_string->length = 2;
    new_string->the_string = realloc(new_string->the_string, sizeof(char) * 2);

    for (int i = 1; i < the_old_string->length; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\t%i\n", i, the_old_string->length);
        if (not(the_old_string->the_string[i] == 0x0a and the_old_string->the_string[i - 1] == 0x0a))
        {
            new_string->the_string[i] = the_old_string->the_string[i];
            new_string->length++;
            new_string->the_string = realloc(new_string->the_string, sizeof(char) * new_string->length);
        }
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

According to gdb, the line

```
new_string->length = 1;
```

Somehow changes the_old_string?

The Add.asm file I'm testing this one is here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZzcMIUETv3u3sdpM_oTJSTetpVee3KZ/view

Under projects/06/Add.asm

Comment: `sizeof(argv[1]` is the size of a pointer not the length of the argument, You probably want `strlen` instead. `string *one_big_string;` and `string *new_string;` and both uninitialized pointers. You need to point them to allocated memory using `malloc. Like `string *new_string = malloc(sizeof(string));` You need to free them when you're done too.

Comment: @RetiredNinja When I free(new_string), does that also free new_string->the_string or do I have to free both?

Comment: You need to free both. The member variable first.

Comment: Thank you! Can you leave an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `string *one_big_string; one_big_string->the_string = malloc(sizeof(char));` is undefined behavior.  The variable `one_big_string` is not initialized, so attempting to reference `one_big_string->the_string` is an error.  You cannot assign `one_big_string->the_string` until after `one_big_string` has been given a valid value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int a = sizeof(argv[1]);
```

`sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer, and not the pointed to data. You need `strlen()` to calculate the length of `argv[1]` here. Do note that you need to first ascertain whether `argv[1][a-5]` is valid before accessing it.

Alternatively, you can use `strcchr()` and `strcmp()` to check if `argv[1]` ends with `".asm"`:

```
const char *const point = strcchr(argv[1], '.');

if (point && !strcmp(point, ".asm")) {
    /* The file ends with .asm. */
} else {
   /* Handle error here. */
}
```

```
string *one_big_string;
one_big_string->the_string = malloc(sizeof(char));  // Aside: You can leave out sizeof(char). It is defined by the standard to be 1
one_big_string->length = 0;
```

The contents of `one_big_string` are indeterminate here. It doesn't point to anything meaningful. You need to first allocate space for `one_big_string`, and then allocate memory for its member. There's a similar problem with `new_string`.

You then need to `free()` this memory in the reverse order in which you allocated it.